# Karate api testing- assertion getting failed when version 1.1.0 and 1.2.0.RC1 is used . Same assertion is passing when 1.0.1 and 1.0.0 version is uesd

Tags: karate

Feature file with scenario

```
Feature: reqres api test cases
  Scenario: list all users get request
    Given url "https://reqres.in/api"
    And path "/users?page=2"
    When method get
    Then print response
    And match response.data[0] == {"last_name": "Lawson","id": "#ignore","avatar": "#ignore","first_name": "Michael","email": "michael.lawson@reqres.in"}
```

Error message in ide

```
match failed: EQUALS
$ | not equal | actual does not contain key - 'last_name' (MAP:MAP)
  {"id":1,"name":"cerulean","year":2000,"color":"#98B2D1","pantone_value":"15-4020"}
  {"id":"#ignore","last_name":"Lawson","avatar":"#ignore","first_name":"Michael","email":"michael.lawson@reqres.in"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using Karate correctly. Note the usage of `param` below:

```
Given url "https://reqres.in/api"
And path "/users"
And param page = 2
When method get
```